# Rails validating enum

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, validation, enum

The Ruby on Rails framework doesn't allow you to validate enums submitted through a form in any sane manner. Evidently, [enums are meant to be used to maintain internal application state](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13971), and are not supposed to be user-facing. Well, in my case it doesn't matter too much, but I still want validations *just in case*.

Here is a widely-used enum:

```
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true

    enum language: {
        arabic: 0,
        chinese: 1,
        english: 2,
        french: 3,
        german: 4,
        italian: 5,
        japanese: 6,
        russian: 7,
        spanish: 8,
        other: 9
    }
end
```

In my schema, the field using this enum is a `text` array: `t.text     "audio_languages",    default: []`, allowing multiple languages to be selected through the form.

In the form, the values are added as a list of check boxes:

[image: HTML form]

In the controller, the values for that field come in as:

`"audio_languages"=>["English", ""]`

Notice the last array entry, `""`. That's just how it works I guess, nothing I've tried gets rid of that, so I have to handle it in the validation.

**In the validation, a language needs to be chosen, and the chosen language has to be present in the `language` enum**:

```
def validate_audio_languages

    # Remove the empty string, which is an artifact of form submission of an array
    # field, during validation
    audio_languages.reject! { |l| l.empty? }

    if !audio_languages.any?
        errors.add(:audio_languages, "need to select a language")
    end

    # If any of the audio languages is invalid, add the error and break
    audio_languages.each do |al|
        valid = false
        Language.languages.each do |l, i|
            valid = true if (al.downcase == l.downcase)
        end

        if !valid
            errors.add(:audio_languages, "not a valid language selection")
            break
        end
    end
end
```

I'm concerned about the length of the function more than anything. Surely there's an easier way to do this kind of simple validation, especially to validate whether or not a value is actually in the enum. Any help in dealing with this issue is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Ruby's array intersection and check for matches. The empty string passed in your params is irrelevant.

```
def validate_audio_languages 
    if audio_languages.any?
        enums = Language.languages.map(&:first)
        matches = enums & audio_languages.map!(&:downcase)
        matches.present? ? matches : errors.add(:audio_languages, "not a valid language selection")
    else
        errors.add(:audio_languages, "need to select a language")
    end
 end
```

You can shave off a couple more lines at the expense of readability, but it pays to keep things simple and readable.